# Why does decrementing Integer.MIN_VALUE by Math.pow() return the same value?

Tags: java, integer-overflow

on executing :

```
        int p=-2147483648;
        p-=Math.pow(1,0);  
        System.out.println(p);
        p-=1;
        System.out.println(p);
Output: -2147483648
         2147483647
```

So why doesn't Math.pow() overflow the number?

Comment: If both arguments are integers, then the result is exactly equal to the mathematical result of raising the first argument to the power of the second argument if that result can in fact be represented exactly as a `double` value.

[you can read more on the Math javadocs][1]


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We start the discussion by observing that `-2147483648 == Integer.MIN_VALUE` (= -(2³¹)).

The expression `p -= Math.pow(1,0)` has an implicit cast from `double` to `int` since [`Math.pow(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)) returns a `double`. The expression with an explicit cast looks like this

```
p = (int) (p - Math.pow(1,0))
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/N0WJ8p)

Even more spread out, we get

```
double d = p - Math.pow(1,0);
p = (int) d;
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GLDOl1)

As we can see, `d` has the value `-2.147483649E9` (= `-2147483649.0`) `< Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

The behaviour of the cast is governed by [Java 14  JLS, §5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> **5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion**
>
> ...
>
> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type `T` takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a `long`, if `T` is `long`, or to an `int`, if `T` is `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`, as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is `NaN` (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an `int` or long 0.
>    - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value `V`, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are two cases:
>
>      - If `T` is `long`, and this integer value can be represented as a `long`, then the result of the first step is the `long` value `V`.
>      - Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an `int`, then the result of the first step is the `int` value `V`.
>    - Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
>      - **The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or negative infinity), and the result of the first step is the smallest representable value of type `int` or `long`.**
>      - The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type `int` or `long`.
>
> In the second step:
>
> 1. If `T` is `int` or `long`, the result of the conversion is the result of the first step.
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `Math.pow()` operates with arguments of type Double and returns a double. Casting it to int will result in the expected output:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int p=-2147483648;
        p-=(int)Math.pow(1,0);  
        System.out.println(p);
        p-=1;
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

The above produces the following output:

2147483647

2147483646